Specific Issue Relating to Ipyrad Pipeline Step 4
I have recently encountered a continuous problem that I have never had happen before. I keep getting this error message after Step #4 of the ipyrad pipeline (see attached). When I input the command and execute, it runs all the way to 100% completion and then it shoots the error message. Here is the link for the ipyrad pipeline if anyone is curious: https://ipyrad.readthedocs.io/en/master/
Any help is appreciated!
I tried updating my conda environment which did not fix the issue. I decided to google the error message and couldn't find any help on the issue.

This is not about programming or software development. You are asking how to use a bioinformatic assembly and analysis tool. You can check https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ but I am not sure if pure software usage questions are on topic there. The best place to post your issue is probably with ipyrad directly. Read the troubleshooting section on their website and if that doesn't help, they encourage to ask questions here
